# Google App Engine push task timing out on flex environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently I have a Google App Engine push task queue that is designed to generate reports from querying BigQuery DB.

The push tasks are generated by cron, which adds a reporting task to the queue

Here is the queue configuration:

```
- name: reporting-push-queue
  target: reporting-dispatcher
  rate: 1/m
  bucket_size: 5
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 60
    max_backoff_seconds: 120
    max_doublings: 5
    task_retry_limit: 2
    task_age_limit: 10m
```

For small queries this configuration is able to run and generate the report correctly. On slightly longer queries it would time out and return a 502 status code after 30 seconds.

Based on the documentation push tasks on flex environments are suppose to have up to 10 minutes but this has not been the case.

Here are the lib versions that I am using with Python 3

```
google-cloud==0.34
google-cloud-bigquery==1.5
google-cloud-pubsub==0.37
```

Here is the yaml file that is used.

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT reporting-dispatcher:app
threadsafe: true

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

service: reporting-dispatcher

instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
  max_concurrent_requests: 1

liveness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 60
  timeout_sec: 60
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 1

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 60
  timeout_sec: 60
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 1
```

Comment: The timeout can be set as part of the entrypoint in yaml per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT reporting-dispatcher:app --timeout=600

Allows the worker to run for 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration looks good! I had similar problems and in my case I hit the 32MB limit for **incoming** http-requests.
As Google states:

> **Incoming bandwidth**
>
> The amount of data received by the application from
> requests. Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.
> This includes:
>
> - Data received by the application in secure requests and non-secure
> - requests uploads to the Blobstore data received in response to HTTP
> - requests by the URL fetch service [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas)

So it could be that you're downloading a resulting table that's too large for the #@MB limit? Not sure if API count towards this, I would guess it does.

What is the task exactly doing?
If you just have a query to run, why not start a job and poll every few seconds to see if it completed, or use another task even. [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) No need to keep the connection open it seems.

By the way, the 32MB limit is ridiculously small these days in my opinion.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#querying-data

Comment: The tasks I am running are for computing the some KPIs of our app, which contains at least a few million data points per day. 

I haven't thought about just starting the job and adding a poll task. I'll look into doing that.